# Hibernate SQLQuery - Get Object by name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a method to get a Category by its "id" and I need a similar method to get a Category by its "name". I did these methods by using Hibernate. How can I fix my second method to get a Category by name?
My source code is as follow:

```
// It works
@Override
public Category getById(int id) {
    return (Category) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Category.class, id);
}

// It doesn't works
@Override
public Category getByName(String name) {
    return (Category) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
        createSQLQuery("SELECT FROM Category WHERE name="+name);
}
```

I have this error with the second method:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl cannot
>   be cast to com.sedae.model.Category

These are my controllers.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCategoryById/{id}")
public String getCategoryById(Model model, @PathVariable ("id") int id){
    model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.getById(id));
    return "/getCategoryById";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getCategoryByName/{name}")
public String getCategoryByName(Model model, @PathVariable("name") String name){
    model.addAttribute("category", categoryService.getByName(name));
    return "/getCategoryByName";
}
```

Thanks in advance people.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure you have only one entry per category name in your table then you can use [Query#uniqueResult](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29):

```
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
        createQuery("from Category where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
Category category = (Category) query.uniqueResult();
```

Make sure to handle the exceptions thrown by uniqueResult.

Comment: Thanks dude! One question more please. Suppose I have two categories (with different ids, obviously) How can I get an specific category by avoiding the error "query did not return an  unique result: 2". ?

Comment: In that case the query returns a list,you can iterate over the list and get the object you want or if you want any one of the object with same category name then you can use `query.setMaxResults(1);`, this returns the first encountered category with the specified category name.

Comment: Hi @user3487063, thanks for the answer, I've changed my method, now it has two parameters "id" and "name", and when I need to make a list by name my query select the category by id and name, there is no problem with duplicated names. Thanks for ask dude.